# jquery validation only validates first field - others are ignored

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I'm using a [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) which should validate all the inputs in a form, but it stops at the first one. If you click on the second input and leave it blank - everything is ok - it validates...
Otherwise - not...

I found some of the same answers - no success...

Here's my fiddle with the example I wrote

[FiddleError](http://jsfiddle.net/2gLRS/)

```
//
//  jQuery Validate example script
//
//  Prepared by David Cochran
//
//  Free for your use -- No warranties, no guarantees!
//

$(document).ready(function(){

// Validate
// http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/
// http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

    $('.validate').validate({
        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).parent().removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        success: function(element) {
            element.closest().removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        }
  });

}); // end document.ready`enter code here`
```

Using:

- Bootstrap
- jQuery
- jQuery validation

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `name` for the fields instead of `id`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="login_id">Login id:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="login_id">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control required" name="password">
    <div class="forgot"> <a href="#">
                    Forgot your password?
                </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zgqHC/)

Comment: Well.. that's akward :D Thank's a lot :)

Comment: @Sparky I'm really sorry, but how can i do that?

Founded :D

Comment: @Modestas,  you already did it by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: @Sparky Edited the how can i do that to Founded :) Thank's anyway

Comment: @ModestasMV, Yeah... "founded" ?  I think you meant, "found it".

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not tell .validate() which fields are required. From the plugin documentation at: http://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method

To make a field required:

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    fruit: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

In this case, the field called "fruit" is required.

Comment: Well, my form tells the code to validate the fields, so it's not the problem :)

Comment: That's one way, yes, but I think it's easier to just put the attribute `required` in the field itself: `<input type="text" name="firstname" required>`. This also works if you use a class, like so: `<input type="text" name="firstname" class="required">`.